# How to go back to HomePage by using base page that contains SplitView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I'm having a problem related to handle events. I had MainPage which contained a SplitView. It might be a base page. There were 2 buttons used to navigate frame in SplitView.Contant. A button is used to navigate to HomePage. The other is used to navigate to a page that contains a form to fill some fields. the page's name is AddSomething. I want to back to my home page immediately after clicking on button "Save".

MainPage XAML:

```xml
<SplitView x:Name="MainMenu" DisplayMode="Overlay">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="BtHome"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Content="Home"/>
                <Button x:Name="BtAddSth"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Content="Add Something"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <SplitView.Content>
        <Frame x:Name="NavigatedFrame"/> <-! That's used to navigate -->
    </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>`
```

AddSomthingPage XAML:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox x:Name="Name" PlaceholderText="Name"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Place" PlaceholderText="Place"/>

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="BtSaveToDB"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Content="Save"/>
            <Button x:Name="BtReset"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="Reset"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

When I click on button "Save", I can go back to the home page. I don't want any change in my xaml. Especially I don't want to load MainPage anymore.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you click save

```
// this will tell NavigatedFrame to go 
// back to previous page, assume that you set it to navigate to MainPage first
NavigatedFrame.GoBack()
```

In MainPage.xaml, add this line to thet Page node

```
NavigationCacheMode="Required"
```

It will cache the mainpage and prevent it from loading again.

Comment: And will it load my HomePage again by the way?

Comment: 'It will cache the mainpage and prevent it from loading again'

Comment: I mean how I can capture event click of button "save". because it isn't in MainPage. So, how can I implement your code in it?

Comment: You need to put SplitView in a new Page called ContainerPage, then navigate NavigatedFrame to MainPage.

In ContainerPage, you handle all button click. This way the SplitView will be available as long as you are not navigate from the ContainerPage

Comment: I did. I had MainPage as a base page that contained SplitView and other pages named HomePage and AddSomethingPage. The button "Save" is in AddSomethingPage. My purpose is how to handle all button click events in MainPage.

Comment: There are 2 option to achive that:
- Use a Messenger system (e.g: MVVM Light) to notify MainPage (or you can use global event).
- Using custom Navigation service to handle the navigation.

Comment: Yeah. I've just thought about it. Let me try. Thank you